# joining 2 parts without losing their textures

Tags: uv-image-editor

I am new to blender, still learning.  its a long process
I have 2 complex pieces created, each with a UV-map and texture.
- if I "join" them the new piece has a single messed-up texture, 1 UV map
How can i get a new UM-Map that has the previous faces still correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you join two meshes together, your parent mesh will be the default material.

You need to create a second material for your second mesh and use the UV Map node under Input to tell it which UV to use.

[image]

It's a good idea you give each UV a name too.As you can see, whichever UV is highlighted is what you can see in the viewport. You can ignore that. It will render both.

[image]